# Should I include all my sources in my PhoneGap app, or request them from a remote server?

Tags: javascript, performance, cordova, cdn

I'm currently trying out PhoneGap, and by the looks of it I'll probably need to use at least one framework: jQuery Mobile, Bootstrap, whatever. Either way, I'll need to reference that code in my app's `index.html`. I heard that when you do that on a website, you should always request code from a (popular) CDN because unless you're requesting a super-new version of the framework, there's a good chance the client already has a cached copy. Is this the same for apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would include it in the app. A PhoneGap app runs entirely from your phone, unlike a website, which you fetch from the internet. If you use a CDN your app now requires the user to have an internet connection to use the app. Depending on your app, this might not be a big issue if it already requires a connection to work properly.

Comment: Right, so the user will have to have a connection when they use it for the first time, but what about afterwards? Will it cache?

Comment: I'm not sure how caching would work in that case. Personally, I would still include the framework in the app.

Comment: Even if it would cache the first time. Maybe it would fetch a new version which breaks your code. I would definitely include it to make sure it works.